# Angular 4, Content of Login page is diaplaying in dashboard page

Tags: angular

I want to route two simple pages.
If I route on dashboard from login page but login page also displays on dashboard page.
Need assistance.

Code is below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'to my First Angular App !';
}
.......................
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';    

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your routing:

```
{path: 'login', component: AppComponent},
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
```